# Badge icon on GreaseMonkey

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey-4

I am using GreaseMonkey on the latest version of Firefox on Windows 10 and was wondering if there is a way when Greasemonkey is enabled and you visit a site to show a badge icon of the active scripts for that tab.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the number of scripts running on that tab?

If so, ViolentMonkey, TamperMonkey & FireMonkey have that feature but GreaseMonkey doesn't.

In GreaseMonkey, if you click the icon, the popup shows the **User scripts for this tab**.

Comment: You are absolutely right - I switch to TamperMonkey and everything is working as expected (and you can import your GreaseMonkey scripts as well unchanged, which is a bonus)! Many thanks!